# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') - nuxtjs / vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a shopify/nuxtjs app and trying to get the sum of all the items in the cart, but I'm getting an error with this code.

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CartIcon',
  data: function(){
    return{
      sum: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    count() {
      let lineItems =  this.$store.getters["checkout/checkout"].lineItems;

      this.sum = lineItems.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator + item.quantity, 0);
      return sum ? (sum >= 99 ? "99+" : sum) : 0;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like your getter is undefined at the moment you try to reduce it. Try to `console.log(lineItems)`. To understand why it is undefined we need to see the actual code of your checkout getter

Comment: As told above, we need more details here. You could maybe import some `mapGetters` here.